# Nulo en model mvc

Tags: c#, mvc, controller, model-view-controller

Tengo este problema:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Vista:**

```
@model IEnumerable<ProvidusHomeWeb.Models.Usuarios>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Providus</title>
</head>
<body>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=> item.usuario)   
    }
</body>
</html>
```

**Controlador:**

```
public ActionResult Login(string uname, string psw)
        {
            try
            {
                ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
                var caracteres = Convert.ToString(psw);
                var usuario = sql.login(uname, psw);

                if (usuario.Count <= 0)
                {
                    ViewBag.MensajeUsuario = "El usuario es inexistente.";
                }
                else if (usuario[0].nivel == 0
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 1
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 2
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 7)
                {
                    return View("Login1");
                }
                else if (usuario[0].nivel == 3
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 4
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 16)
                {
                    return View("Login2");
                }
                else 
                {
                    return View("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return View("");
        }
    }
```

**Clase:**

```
public class Usuarios
    {
        public string usuario { get; set; }
        public decimal? nivel { get; set; }

        public Usuarios(string usuario, decimal? nivel)
        {
            this.usuario = usuario;
            this.nivel = nivel;
        }
    }
```

**ConexionSQL:**

```
public List<Usuarios> login(string usu, string cla)
        {
            List<Usuarios> salida = new List<Usuarios>();
            string con = "cadena";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT Count(*), nivel " +
                    "FROM usuarios " +
                    "WHERE usuario = @usu " +
                    "AND clave = @cla " +
                    "AND AccesoSistemaProvidus = 1";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usu", usu);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cla", cla);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string usuario = dr["usuario"]?.ToString();
                    string clave = dr["clave"]?.ToString();
                    decimal? nivel = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["nivel"]?.ToString());
                    Usuarios u = new Usuarios(usuario, clave, nivel);
                    salida.Add(u);
                }
                connection.Close();
                return salida;
            }
        }
```

Entiendo que el problema es que no le estoy pasando el modelo al controlador pero, ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: Al añadir `usuario[0]` sucede esto: `El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'ProvidusHomeWeb.Models.Usuarios', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ProvidusHomeWeb.Models.Usuarios]'. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar  `View("ViewName", model)` en `controler` donde defines el nombre de la `vista`, con su respectivo `modelo` dependiendo si la `vista` no pertenece a la `accion` actual del controlador. las vistas deberan pertenecer a las acciones del controlador

Ejemplo:

```
 if (usuario[0].nivel == 0
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 1
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 2
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 7)
                {
                    return View(usuario);//suponiendo que esta es la vista de la accion actual
                }
                else if (usuario[0].nivel == 3
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 4
                    || usuario[0].nivel == 16)
                {
                    return View("Login2",usuario);
                }
                else 
                {
                    return View("Index",usuario);
                }
```

En caso de que las vista pertenescan a un controlador distinto puedes utilizar.

```
return RedirectToAction("nombreAccion", "nombreController", modelo)
```

si requieres solo el acceso detalle del modelo usuario y no a una coleccion de usuarios aplica en la accion:

`return View(usuario[0])`
y en la vista `@model ProvidusHomeWeb.Models.Usuarios`